# Batch file to extract text from multiples txt files in multiples folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In the below code, I want to extract the specific string `this is Version` after a certain string, from log file `myFile.log` that can be found in subdirectory of the directory using a batch file.

Please help me to extract this specific string `this is Version` from multiples log files in multiples directories (this directories have the same content).

I have the log file with the following informations (this is just a part of `myFile.log`):

> ```
> 2020-09-18 11:19:27,120 INFO  [Tollbox.wizar] (ServerService ) Starting, Thi is Version: 1.02.8 - September 18, 2020, appender 
> 2020-09-18 11:19:27,120 INFO  [Tollbox.wizar] (ServerService ) Starting, View360 networks  
> 2020-09-18 11:19:27,120 INFO  [Tollbox.wizar] (ServerService ) Starting, Solidworks workgroup  
> 2020-09-18 11:19:27,120 INFO  [Tollbox.wizar] (ServerService ) Starting, Compiled(32-bit) - September 18, 2020, appender
> ```

Example:

> ```
> folder1\test\myFile.log
> folder2\test\myFile.log
> folder3\test\myFile.log
> ```

```
@echo off > newfile & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN

set C=
set A=

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /v /n "\\\\\\" ^< C:\folder1\test\myFile.log') do (

echo.%%b|find "this is Version" > nul && if not defined C set C=%%a

)

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /v /n "\\\\\\" ^< C:\folder1\test\myFile.log') do (
if %%a equ !C! (
set S=%%b
set S=!S:this is Version=!
>> C:\newfile.txt echo.!S!
)
if %%a gtr !C! if %%a lss !A! >> C:\newfile.txt echo.%%b
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: We need to see a real world example of the log file you are parsing.

Comment: Satcha, do you think that information would be better in your Question instead of a comment?  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: sorry fixed. thanks

Comment: Can you explain why the `FIND` command is configured to exclude lines that contain \\\\\\ instead of just configuring it to include lines that contain *This is version*?

Comment: it just to display lines not containing the string specified

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output (by [edit]ing your question)! What is the variable `A` intended for, which is never set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think much too complicated. Get the correct line, remove the part from the front up to (including) `Version:`  and get the first token from the rest:

```
@echo off 
setlocal 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('find "This is Version:" myfile.log') do set "version=%%a"
for /f %%a in ("%version:*Version: =%") do set "version=%%a"
echo "%version%"
```